# How to handle 401 errors in a Redux/React application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a site with React and Redux and I have a query about how I should be handling 401 status responses.

Currently when the API reports a 401 HTTP Status it is usually caught in one of my actions and I dispatch:

```
return dispatch({
    type: 'FETCH_MONTHLY_DATA_FAILURE',
    error: response.data
});
```

And the related reducer checks the HTTP status code and I have some Redux middleware that checks for this HTTPStatus state value and reacts accordingly.

Is there a more elegant way I can handle these errors in a general manner? I am using Axios for my HTTP requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said :

> And the related reducer checks the HTTP status code...

Using a middleware is great but **the reducer should not check for the http status.** It would be outside of its purpose.

From the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) :

> The reducer job is to specify how the application's state changes in
>   response.

Your action-creators should be pure, all the async codes should live somewhere else.

**Side effects do not belong in reducers**

There are many ways to do it. It all comes down to preferences.

Here are 3 ways to handle HTTP requests in a more elegant way:

**Option 1 (the most powerful one) : Generators, Sagas and complex chains of asynchronous operations**

[redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) allows you to do just that. I personally use this middleware to handle my api calls and responses.

> The mental model is that a saga is like a separate thread in your
>   application that's solely responsible for side effects. redux-saga is
>   a redux middleware, which means this thread can be started, paused and
>   cancelled from the main application with normal redux actions, it has
>   access to the full redux application state and it can dispatch redux
>   actions as well.

Here are the benefits I get from using this option :

- isolate side-effect code to a single domain of the application(sagas)
- composition of multiple sagas(complex with promises)
- reduces promise boilerplate action
- creators are pure so much easier to test!

Simplify implementation of use cases like:

- In a large multi-user, multi-department blog, if a user had ever
  clicked on a "subscribe to RSS Feed" button, then the next time the
  user visits a section that has a dedicated RSS feed, show him/her a
  suggestion to subscribe to this section's feed.
- In an online IDE, if a user has never used a particular feature of an
  application, but has arrived at a state that the aforementioned
  feature might potentially be useful, show a help dialog introducing
  this feature.
- In stackoverflow, while the user was responding to a question, the
  question has been changed by OP so you inform the user that the
  question has been changed and the answer is potentially no longer
  valid.
- etc.

[redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) is another option :

Compose and cancel async actions to create side effects and more.

**Option 2 : put the intelligence that drives asynchronous operations in your application operations in actions creators**

[redux-promise](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) are good exemples.

So far so good. We removed the coupling, separated our the async logic somewhere else and have a clean architecture. However, redux-saga's more advanced feature will simplify complex use cases.

Here is the gist of redux thunk :

> Asynchronous middleware like redux-thunk or redux-promise wraps the
>   store's dispatch() method and allows you to dispatch something other
>   than actions, for example, functions or Promises. Any middleware you
>   use can then interpret anything you dispatch, and in turn, can pass
>   actions to the next middleware in the chain. For example, a Promise
>   middleware can intercept Promises and dispatch a pair of begin/end
>   actions asynchronously in response to each Promise.

**Option 3 : Managing side effects through Higher order components**

Higher-Order Components (HOCs) are JavaScript functions which add functionality to existing component classes. Just as React components let you add functionality to an application, Higher-Order Components let you add functionality to components. You could say they’re components for components.

[Not ideal for all use cases !](https://hashnode.com/post/what-are-the-benefits-of-redux-thunk-over-redux-saga-what-pros-and-cons-do-they-have-over-each-other-ciqvyydh7065w3g53ffalif61)

Exemple : [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), a promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

**Option 4 : Generators and promises, sans Sagas**

Last but not the least, you can still use generators to manage your async control flow, in frontend, without adding redux-thunk dependency, if you do not need some of its advanced features.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at redux saga. I understand/feel my current approach using reducers/middleware isn’t ideal and this prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for the delay. I’ve only just had time to have a proper look at redux-saga. I’m currently using redux-thunk. I can see some advantages of switching to redux-saga. However, I did solve the current problem by revisiting Axios response interceptors and using React Router’s browserHistory to push/replace to a sign-in page. This seems enough for my issue and allows me to remove the dependency of middleware/reducers checking the HTTP status. I think Andreyco’s answer is great but I agree that reducers aren’t the best place to check this. Thank you for your input with react-saga

Comment: @DrBeza I have updated my answer with pros and cons of each more elegant solution I could find! Please accept my answer if I have answered your question properly now.

Answer (score 13):

Add global response interceptor which dispatches action when error occurs

```
import store from './store';

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    store.dispatch({
        type: 'API_ERROR',
        payload: error,
    })
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// In you reducers...
reduce(state, action) {
    if (action.type === 'API_ERROR' && action.payload.statusCode === 401) {
        return { // whatever needed }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: This looks great. However I'm creating store in my App.js `const store = configureStore();` from an import - do I need to refactor this for this approach to work?

Comment: in `App.js`, you can import `axios` and set response interceptor.